# CSS to target A inside LI inside UL

Tags: css

I have HTML like:

```
<ul class="myclass">
<li><a href="www.link.com">stuff here</a></li>
<li><a href="www.link.com">more stuff here</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to capitalize the links so I'm using `text-transform:capitalize !important` but it's not targeting correctly.

Here is my CSS

```
ul.myclass li a{
 text-transform:capitalize !important;
}
```

Also tried

```
ul.myclass li > a{
     text-transform:capitalize !important;
    }
```

and

```
a ul.myclass li{
     text-transform:capitalize !important;
    }
```

```css
ul.myclass li a {
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myclass">
  <li><a href="www.link.com">stuff here</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.link.com">more stuff here</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added a working snippet to show that the code works fine. `capitalize` does what it [says on the tin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform#capitalize_General); it capitalizes the first letter of each word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `text-transform:uppercase`

```css
ul.myclass > li a{
 text-transform:uppercase !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myclass">
<li><a href="www.link.com">stuff here</a></li>
<li><a href="www.link.com">more stuff here</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your a genius!

Comment: would be great if you can approve answer. @UserSN

Comment: Done was on timer before.

Comment: The OP's code already worked as is; this made it work differently. Not sure how this answers the question...

Comment: question only capitalizes the first letter, and he needs the total letters be capitalized. @HereticMonkey

Comment: The OP never says that, only "I'd like to capitalize the links". You were lucky that your interpretation matched the OP's intent.

Comment: regarding user experience, `a` tag text is every-words capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to use `uppercase` instead of `capitalize`
As for the code, it was working fine but your logic was faulty.

For reference, see: [Text transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) 
or
See the code below:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="myclass">
<li><a href="www.link.com">stuff here</a></li>
<li><a href="www.link.com">more stuff here</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.myclass li a{
 text-transform:uppercase ;
}
```